# Media Temple and Heroku CNAME

Tags: heroku, dns, cname, mediatemple

I am using Media Temple to configure my DNS settings for a domain. I recently launched an application on Heroku and want to set a subdomain of my domain to be the CNAME for the Heroku application. The issue is the DNS editor places a period at the end of the Heroku domain name when I enter it as a CNAME, and Heroku shows an error that this is not a valid domain.

In my DNS settings, I have:

```
subdomain.domain.com CNAME appname.herokuapp.com
```

When I save this, it shows up in the settings as

```
subdomain.domain.com CNAME appname.herokuapp.com.
```

Any ideas on how to remove that trailing dot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into this problem the other day when setting up CloudFlare for my Heroku app. "I do not think it means what you think it means."

With Heroku, you have to add domains that your app will be accessible from, even if your managing DNS elsewhere. [Here's there documentation for how to do it](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains). Basically, you can do this from the terminal:

- `cd` into your app's directory
- `heroku domains:add subdomain.domain.com` to add the subdomain like you want.

Also, on mediatemple, I think you might need to put just the `subdomain` part instead of `subdomain.domain.com`, though it'll probably work either way. As shown on the [knowledgebase article from launchrock on adding a CNAME with Media Temple](http://support.launchrock.com/knowledgebase/articles/36669-creating-your-cname-record-mediatemple):

> "5. In the Name field, enter the part of the address you chose to use for your website with
>   LaunchRock. *For example, if you chose signup.yoursite.com, enter signup in the Name field.*"